# App with Crystal Reports Viewer not loading in Windows XP

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have prepared a `wpf application` using visual studio 2010 in windows 7 which includes crystal report viewer.

I tried to run the application on another windows 7 pc with `CR runtime` installed, it worked properly.

I tried the same thing with windows xp but everytime the crystal report loads it gives an unhandled exception and the whole app stops working and closes.

what to do in this case? or give me some suggestions how to make work with window-XP

Answer (score 0):

There is a redistributable (x86/x64) that is a prerequisite for .NET apps that integrate with Crystal Reports .NET

You can download it at the Business Objects "download center":

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0.zip

**more info / links**
http://www.crystalreporthostingnews.com/index.php/archives/282

Comment: i have downloaded and installed the upper CR for VS runtime but still its not working.

Comment: Please clarify "not working". Same issue? App crash?? Have you ever used FuseLog? It logs failures when assemblies are missing, which is typically the cause with a "fail to load" app failure.

Comment: the app crashes whenever the app try to load the crystal report.